# Accessing local/shared drive with Spring MVC

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm pretty new to Spring MVC and need to display contents of local folder (could be NAS too) in browser. The folder has PDF files, which I want to list as URL's. On clicking any of them I should be able to view the file in question in PDF reader. My application server is Tomcat.

On running the app I can see the files as hyperlinks, but on clicking it gives HTTP 404. I think I'm missing out on some configuration somewhere. I've tried all possible settings and even searched for quite some time, but haven't got it to work yet.

Can someone kindly let me know where I'm going wrong or what I could be missing?

My dispatcher-servlet.xml looks like this:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.springapp.mvc"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

Web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

index.jsp:

```
<c:if test="${not empty dir}">
<ul>
    <c:forEach var="listValue" items="${dir}">
        <%--<li>${listValue}</li>--%>
        <%--<li><a href="${listValue}">${listValue}</a></li>--%>
        <li><a href="<c:url value="${listValue}"/>">${listValue}</a></li>
    </c:forEach>
</ul>
</c:if>
```

and the controller class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class DirListController extends AbstractController {
    private File[] getPdfFileListing() {
        File dir = new File("//Users//username//Documents"); // current directory

        return dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws Exception {
        //return back to index.jsp
        File[] files = getPdfFileListing();
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index");
        model.addObject("dir", files);

        return model;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't just access files remotely through an HTTP server.

Comment: You mean even within the same network if a particular folder is accessible on the server where the web app resides, still it won't be readable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing the whole directory at once probably isn't going to work. But what you can do, is return a single file per link as a `byte` array, if you use `ResponseEntity` as a return type. Then you can open it up in a PDF viewer.

Tested this with Spring 3.2.5, Tomcat 7 and added [Apache Commons IO 1.3.2](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-io/1.3.2) as a dependency (for the `FileUtils` class).

```
private static final String DIRECTORY = "/Users/username/Documents/";

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, params = "fileName")
@ResponseBody
protected ResponseEntity<byte[]> handleFileRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                                   @RequestParam String fileName) throws Exception {
    // Change below to proper logger, if you have one configured.
    System.out.println("Trying to find file: " + fileName +
                       " from directory: " + DIRECTORY + ".");

    File pdfFile = new File(DIRECTORY + fileName);
    byte[] bytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(pdfFile);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"));
    headers.setContentLength(bytes.length);
    headers.setContentDispositionFormData("filename", fileName);

    return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(bytes, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Thus you'd have to add a `fileName` request parameter to the link in your URL, where you define which file to call. For instance:

```
<a href="http://localhost:8080/myApp?fileName=test.pdf">Open test.pdf</a>
```

Comment: Does this method mean when i click on the link to a file from the handleRequestInternal() i've in my original question, the file name would be passed in, set as ResponseEntity type & returned back in the browser to be opened up in pdf reader? I added this method in my app but it didn't work, still getting 404 when i click the link. Do i need to change the path in @RequestMapping annotation to reflect the correct path?

Comment: Yes, when you link to it, your browser will ask for instance whether to save or open the file, depending on which browser you are. Also, edited my answer to reflect how to call it.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Thank you for your help. It's working now.