# List files from local directory or with in the same server using Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat7

Good day.
I am developing a Spring MVC web app.
I would like to ask for your help on how I can access and list the files/directories available inside a folder located in local directory or within the same server location of my web-app.
The one I would like to achieve is the about the same on how browsers displays the local directory. Like when you access `file:///C:/` on a browser.

I googled for a long time now and tried many implementation but got no luck
Here are my codes:

**DashboardController.java**

```java
package mypackage.controllers;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class DashboardController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/dashboard", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String dashboardPage(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("username", "erick.acabal");
        model.addAttribute("position", "User");
        model.addAttribute("files", getFileListing());

        return "dashboard";
    }

    private ArrayList getFileListing() {
        File dir = new File("file:///C:/my_data/");
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();

        ArrayList filPaths = new ArrayList();
        for (File file : files) {
            filPaths.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        return filPaths;
    }

}
```

**dashboard.jsp**

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>QAS Dashboard</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h2>QAS Dashboard</h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Welcome</td>
            <td>${username}!</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Position:</td>
            <td>${position}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>File List</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach var="listValue" items="${files}">
            <tr>
                <td><a href="${listValue}">${listValue}</a></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

With these codes, I'm getting a `null` on `dir.listFiles()`.
I also tried the implementation on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20861605/accessing-local-shared-drive-with-spring-mvc) but I can't make it work.

I'm running my web app in `http://localhost:8080/` using Tomcat 7.

I hope someone can point me to the right direction on this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
File dir = new File("file:///C:/my_data/");
```

use

```
File dir = new File("C:/my_data/");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's not working. I'm using Spring-MVC and my web-app is on a Tomcat Server in my localhost

Comment: Very strange, I just created Controller in my test Spring-MVC and could take files on my local as I wrote (without file:// as you should provide path). Are you running your application on same machine?

Comment: I'm running my web-app on a local server within the same machine. I'm using Tomcat 7. Did you get the list of files within you local?